# Is Boost.Preprocessor a set of macros for cpp or a separate processor?

Tags: boost-preprocessor

Is Boost.Preprocessor a set of macros for cpp or a separate processor?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It also has examples. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Comment: "I'm having a difficult time getting an exact answer." -- How odd ... it's not as if the answer is subtle, ambiguous, hidden, or hard to come by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost.Preprocessor is a set of macros that utilises your standard C++ preprocessor to provide some more advanced functionality. It is not a separate preprocessor.

Comment: @Roman It's called "The Boost Library
Preprocessor Subset for C/C++". The answer is ... yes, for the parts that don't depend on C++.

Comment: no parts of Boost.Preprocessor are C++ only. It is all fully C compatible